# Show table data not appearing in context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have an mvc3 application, with a database and I have a DataContext which I use to display data in some Views. I inserted some data into the database with show table data and it's not appearing in the context. Otherwise the whole thing works just fine. What could have happened?

Comment: There's data in your Database but the context is empty? Post the code where you initialize the context and your connection string.

Comment: I don't use any initializer. I use the no parameters constructor for the context and the connection string is in the web config, and it's good.

Comment: I think what's happening is that EF is dropping/creating a new database and it's not using the database that has the data you entered. Look into this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.. Thank you